# Can I use a different email/calendar/address book provider for Mac OS X and iOS?

Tags: mail.app, icloud, ical, contacts

I am afraid that the switch to iCloud will make life very complicated, particularly for Snow Leopard users like myself. I am also afraid that Apple will make life generally more complicated.

So I am wondering if I can theoretically switch to another provide for synced email configurations, address book data and calendars.

I don't mind paying for those services, I just need my address book, emails and calendars to be the same between my devices, ideally between Mac OS X and iOS and everything else (Linux, Windows, Solaris etc.).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Googles Services](https://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740)

### iOS

- **(Push) Email using the IMAP protocol**

  - Push is not default. You have to set it up [manually](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20055823-285/how-to-enable-push-gmail-on-your-ios-device/).
- bi-directional **contacts sync** (Exchange supported)

  - If you do not sync contacts using the exchange protocol, you only sync via iTunes.
- bi-directional **calendars sync**

  - I don't have good experiences with the bi-directional sync using the iOS calendar app. Luckily, there are *plenty* of third-party apps available which offer a tight integration of Google Calender.
     **[CCal](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/ccal-sync-google-calendar/id387569926?mt=8)** has been quite an enhancement to my Google experience.

### OSX

iCal, Address Book and Mail allow to integrate sync with Google's services in **Preferences → Accounts**.

### Google Services on other platforms

Google's Services are more widely available than anything else I know. It allows to keep contacts/calendars/email in sync on OSX, iOS, Android and Linux. In Ubuntu I use Google's Services in Thunderbird and Google Calendar/Contacts extensions.

Comment: Please take my answer with caution. I've used Google's Services on iOS for over a year. But I've recently moved to Android. Some little setup details might have changed.

Comment: Ta. I'll have a look at this. Is Apple's iOS calendar not configurable? How do I "sync contacts using the exchange protocol"?

Comment: I've had plenty of troubles with getting created events on the iPhone to sync with the cloud. But more than that the iOS calendar was missing  *week view* and the ability to show *"connected events"* (events that last for several days).

Comment: You set up contacts sync via exchange by choosing *Exchange instead of Gmail* for your accounts. Once you've setup your exchange account, you can choose to sync email and contacts.

Comment: Sorry. I am confused. Choosing Exchange instead of Gmail where?

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm See [this](https://www.google.com/help/hc/images/mobile_138740c_en.gif).